# jQuery Ajax, moving list items between lists

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm not sure if returning html is the way to go here but I'm not experienced at all with JSON and maybe that's the answer to my problem.

I have two ul lists with items, they all have a select in them and the first list contains all the items with the selected option equal to cero, the other list has the rest:

```
<ul id="invlistsinmesa">
  <li id="inv-56">
      <label>Name 1</label>
        <select>
            <option  value="1">Mesa 1</option>
            <option  value="2">Mesa 2</option>
            <option  value="3">Mesa 3</option>
                    <!-- ... -->                               
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Sin mesa</option>
        </select>
       <div class="delete_box"><a href="#invlistsinmesa" class="close">Delete</a></div>                  
 </li><li id="inv-57">
      <label>Name 2</label>
        <select>
            <option  value="1">Mesa 1</option>
            <option  value="2">Mesa 2</option>
            <option  value="3">Mesa 3</option>
                    <!-- ... -->                               
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Sin mesa</option>
        </select>
       <div class="delete_box"><a href="#invlistsinmesa" class="close">Delete</a></div>                  
 </li>
</ul>
<ul id="invlist">
  <li id="inv-36">
      <label>Name 1</label>
        <select>
            <option  value="1">Mesa 1</option>
            <option  value="2">Mesa 2</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="3">Mesa 3</option>
                    <!-- ... -->                               
            <option value="0">Sin mesa</option>
        </select>
       <div class="delete_box"><a href="#invlistsinmesa" class="close">Delete</a></div>                  
 </li><li id="inv-37">
      <label>Name 2</label>
        <select>
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Mesa 1</option>
            <option value="2">Mesa 2</option>
            <option value="3">Mesa 3</option>
                    <!-- ... -->                               
            <option value="0">Sin mesa</option>
        </select>
       <div class="delete_box"><a href="#invlistsinmesa" class="close">Delete</a></div>                  
 </li>
</ul>
```

As you see there's a lot of code and it all comes from a database. I have a few ajax calls going on here (deleting, adding new items) but the one I have a problem with is when I change the selected option. This is my code now (on change of the select):

EDIT: Added the click function (it's not change because I'm using jqTransform to style the selects but it's the same as using change with a regular select)

```
$('li[id^="inv-"] div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a').on('click', function(){
  var item=($(this).closest("li[id^='inv-']")).attr('id');
  var id = parseInt(item.replace("inv-", ""));
  var nummesa= ($(this).closest('li')).attr('class');

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax-invi.php",
  dataType: "html",
  data: "id="+id,
  success: function(data) {
    if(data>=0){
      if(data!=0){
        noty({"text":"Person has been moved"});
      }else{
        //Here I need to control if the list item needs to 
        //change to the other list or not
      }          
    }else{
      if(data=='-1'){
        noty({"text":"Table is full, person cannot move there","type":"error"});
      }
    }
  }
 }); 
});
```

In my ajax-invi.php file I query de database to see if the person can move to the new selected option (basically you put people in tables, you can't place a person in a full table and that needs to be controlled) and I return -1 if the table is full or 0 if it isn't, but if I need to move it then I have a problem because I'm not returning the html that I need to move.

Comment: Help me understand the desired behavior. Let's say you select a table for inv-56. When you get a return of 0 then you want to move the html for inv-56 from invlistsinmesa to invlist. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions about what you want here, but assuming you want to move the LI from the invlistsinmesa to invlist here is the code you want for moving the data. You don't need any html returned from your call because the HTML is already present in your document. Assuming the id in your .ajax call is the LI id, such as inv-56 then here is the code:

```
var $item = $('#' + id);
$('#invlist').append('<li id=' + id + '>' + $item.html() + '</li>');
$item.remove();
```

Comment: The problem I don't know if the user will change the value of the select to 0 or to another number. If the select value is 1 and he changes to 3, the item shouldn't move (just change the database). It should only move if he choses 0.

Comment: If the item is in the top list and your selected choice > 0 then you would move it, right? Similarly, if the item is in the bottom list and you select 0 it moves back to the top list, correct?

Comment: Can you update the code in your post to include the entire on change function?

Comment: I edited my code but it isn't much of a change. Also my values are correct, I checked them on firebug. It's more of a matter of not knowing how to handle them to get the desired outcome.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that connects with the change event from the SELECT elements. All I see is code that handles the delete button, but your AJAX call is related to the SELECT, not the DELETE.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9167/discussion-between-davidethell-and-elaine-marley)